# 404 error in web hosting in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, web-hosting

I have hosted a codeigniter project using the 000webhosting site according to the mentioned steps by professionals but i do find the 404 error in viewing my website.

**Here is my config.php file**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('Direct script access allowed');

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Base Site URL
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
  | WITH a trailing slash:
  |
  | http://example.com/
  |
  | If this is not set then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol, domain
  | and path to your installation. However, you should always configure this
  | explicitly and never rely on auto-guessing, especially in production
  | environments.
  |
 */

$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';



//$root = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
//$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
//$config['base_url'] = $root;

//$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/kawshi/';

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Index File
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
  | something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
  | variable so that it is blank.
  |
 */
//$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | URI PROTOCOL
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
  | URI string.  The default setting of 'REQUEST_URI' works for most servers.
  | If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
  |
  | 'REQUEST_URI'    Uses $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
  | 'QUERY_STRING'   Uses $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
  | 'PATH_INFO'      Uses $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
  |
  | WARNING: If you set this to 'PATH_INFO', URIs will always be URL-decoded!
 */
//$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | URL suffix
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | This option allows you to add a suffix to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter.
  | For more information please see the user guide:
  |
  | http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */

//$config['url_suffix'] = '';

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Default Language
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | This determines which set of language files should be used. Make sure
  | there is an available translation if you intend to use something other
  | than english.
  |
 */
$config['language'] = 'english';

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Default Character Set
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | This determines which character set is used by default in various methods
  | that require a character set to be provided.
  |
  | See http://php.net/htmlspecialchars for a list of supported charsets.
  |
 */
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Enable/Disable System Hooks
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | If you would like to use the 'hooks' feature you must enable it by
  | setting this variable to TRUE (boolean).  See the user guide for details.
  |
 */
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Class Extension Prefix
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | This item allows you to set the filename/classname prefix when extending
  | native libraries.  For more information please see the user guide:
  |
  | http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html
  | http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html
  |
 */
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Composer auto-loading
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Enabling this setting will tell CodeIgniter to look for a Composer
  | package auto-loader script in application/vendor/autoload.php.
  |
  | $config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
  |
  | Or if you have your vendor/ directory located somewhere else, you
  | can opt to set a specific path as well:
  |
  | $config['composer_autoload'] = '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
  |
  | For more information about Composer, please visit http://getcomposer.org/
  |
  | Note: This will NOT disable or override the CodeIgniter-specific
  | autoloading (application/config/autoload.php)
 */
$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Allowed URL Characters
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | This lets you specify which characters are permitted within your URLs.
  | When someone tries to submit a URL with disallowed characters they will
  | get a warning message.
  |
  | As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
  | as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-
  |
  | Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
  |
  | The configured value is actually a regular expression character group
  | and it will be executed as: ! preg_match('/^[<permitted_uri_chars>]+$/i
  |
  | DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!
  |
 */
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';


/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Enable Query Strings
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | By default CodeIgniter uses search-engine friendly segment based URLs:
  | example.com/who/what/where/
  |
  | By default CodeIgniter enables access to the $_GET array.  If for some
  | reason you would like to disable it, set 'allow_get_array' to FALSE.
  |
  | You can optionally enable standard query string based URLs:
  | example.com?who=me&what=something&where=here
  |
  | Options are: TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
  |
  | The other items let you set the query string 'words' that will
  | invoke your controllers and its functions:
  | example.com/index.php?c=controller&m=function
  |
  | Please note that some of the helpers won't work as expected when
  | this feature is enabled, since CodeIgniter is designed primarily to
  | use segment based URLs.
  |
 */
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Error Logging Threshold
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | If you have enabled error logging, you can set an error threshold to
  | determine what gets logged. Threshold options are:
  | You can enable error logging by setting a threshold over zero. The
  | threshold determines what gets logged. Threshold options are:
  |
  | 0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
  | 1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
  | 2 = Debug Messages
  | 3 = Informational Messages
  | 4 = All Messages
  |
  | You can also pass an array with threshold levels to show individual error types
  |
  |     array(2) = Debug Messages, without Error Messages
  |
  | For a live site you'll usually only enable Errors (1) to be logged otherwise
  | your log files will fill up very fast.
  |
 */
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Error Logging Directory Path
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
  | application/logs/ directory. Use a full server path with trailing slash.
  |
 */
$config['log_path'] = '';

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Log File Extension
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | The default filename extension for log files. The default 'php' allows for
  | protecting the log files via basic scripting, when they are to be stored
  | under a publicly accessible directory.
  |
  | Note: Leaving it blank will default to 'php'.
  |
 */
$config['log_file_extension'] = '';

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Log File Permissions
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | The file system permissions to be applied on newly created log files.
  |
  | IMPORTANT: This MUST be an integer (no quotes) and you MUST use octal
  |            integer notation (i.e. 0700, 0644, etc.)
 */
$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Date Format for Logs
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Each item that is logged has an associated date. You can use PHP date
  | codes to set your own date formatting
  |
 */
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Error Views Directory Path
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
  | application/views/errors/ directory.  Use a full server path with trailing slash.
  |
 */
$config['error_views_path'] = '';

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Cache Directory Path
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
  | application/cache/ directory.  Use a full server path with trailing slash.
  |
 */
$config['cache_path'] = '';

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Cache Include Query String
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Set this to TRUE if you want to use different cache files depending on the
  | URL query string.  Please be aware this might result in numerous cache files.
  |
 */
$config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Encryption Key
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | If you use the Encryption class, you must set an encryption key.
  | See the user guide for more info.
  |
  | http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html
  |
 */
$config['encryption_key'] = 'REALLY_LONG_NUMBER';

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Session Variables
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | 'sess_driver'
  |
  | The storage driver to use: files, database, redis, memcached
  |
  | 'sess_cookie_name'
  |
  | The session cookie name, must contain only [0-9a-z_-] characters
  |
  | 'sess_expiration'
  |
  | The number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
  | Setting to 0 (zero) means expire when the browser is closed.
  |
  | 'sess_save_path'
  |
  | The location to save sessions to, driver dependant.
  |
  | For the 'files' driver, it's a path to a writable directory.
  | For the 'database' driver, it's a table name.
  | Please read up the manual for the format with other session drivers.
  |
  | IMPORTANT: You are REQUIRED to set a valid save path!
  |
  | 'sess_match_ip'
  |
  | Whether to match the user's IP address when reading the session data.
  |
  | 'sess_time_to_update'
  |
  | How many seconds between CI regenerating the session ID.
  |
  | 'sess_regenerate_destroy'
  |
  | Whether to destroy session data associated with the old session ID
  | when auto-regenerating the session ID. When set to FALSE, the data
  | will be later deleted by the garbage collector.
  |
  | Other session cookie settings are shared with the rest of the application,
  | except for 'cookie_prefix' and 'cookie_httponly', which are ignored here.
  |
 */
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Cookie Related Variables
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | 'cookie_prefix'   = Set a cookie name prefix if you need to avoid collisions
  | 'cookie_domain'   = Set to .your-domain.com for site-wide cookies
  | 'cookie_path'     = Typically will be a forward slash
  | 'cookie_secure'   = Cookie will only be set if a secure HTTPS connection exists.
  | 'cookie_httponly' = Cookie will only be accessible via HTTP(S) (no javascript)
  |
  | Note: These settings (with the exception of 'cookie_prefix' and
  |       'cookie_httponly') will also affect sessions.
  |
 */
$config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
$config['cookie_domain'] = '';
$config['cookie_path'] = '/';
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly'] = FALSE;

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Standardize newlines
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Determines whether to standardize newline characters in input data,
  | meaning to replace \r\n, \r, \n occurences with the PHP_EOL value.
  |
  | This is particularly useful for portability between UNIX-based OSes,
  | (usually \n) and Windows (\r\n).
  |
 */
$config['standardize_newlines'] = FALSE;

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Global XSS Filtering
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Determines whether the XSS filter is always active when GET, POST or
  | COOKIE data is encountered
  |
  | WARNING: This feature is DEPRECATED and currently available only
  |          for backwards compatibility purposes!
  |
 */
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Cross Site Request Forgery
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Enables a CSRF cookie token to be set. When set to TRUE, token will be
  | checked on a submitted form. If you are accepting user data, it is strongly
  | recommended CSRF protection be enabled.
  |
  | 'csrf_token_name' = The token name
  | 'csrf_cookie_name' = The cookie name
  | 'csrf_expire' = The number in seconds the token should expire.
  | 'csrf_regenerate' = Regenerate token on every submission
  | 'csrf_exclude_uris' = Array of URIs which ignore CSRF checks
 */
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Output Compression
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Enables Gzip output compression for faster page loads.  When enabled,
  | the output class will test whether your server supports Gzip.
  | Even if it does, however, not all browsers support compression
  | so enable only if you are reasonably sure your visitors can handle it.
  |
  | Only used if zlib.output_compression is turned off in your php.ini.
  | Please do not use it together with httpd-level output compression.
  |
  | VERY IMPORTANT:  If you are getting a blank page when compression is enabled it
  | means you are prematurely outputting something to your browser. It could
  | even be a line of whitespace at the end of one of your scripts.  For
  | compression to work, nothing can be sent before the output buffer is called
  | by the output class.  Do not 'echo' any values with compression enabled.
  |
 */
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Master Time Reference
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Options are 'local' or any PHP supported timezone. This preference tells
  | the system whether to use your server's local time as the master 'now'
  | reference, or convert it to the configured one timezone. See the 'date
  | helper' page of the user guide for information regarding date handling.
  |
 */
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Rewrite PHP Short Tags
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | If your PHP installation does not have short tag support enabled CI
  | can rewrite the tags on-the-fly, enabling you to utilize that syntax
  | in your view files.  Options are TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
  |
 */
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;


/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Reverse Proxy IPs
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | If your server is behind a reverse proxy, you must whitelist the proxy
  | IP addresses from which CodeIgniter should trust headers such as
  | HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and HTTP_CLIENT_IP in order to properly identify
  | the visitor's IP address.
  |
  | You can use both an array or a comma-separated list of proxy addresses,
  | as well as specifying whole subnets. Here are a few examples:
  |
  | Comma-separated:    '10.0.1.200,192.168.5.0/24'
  | Array:      array('10.0.1.200', '192.168.5.0/24')
 */
$config['proxy_ips'] = '';
```

**Here is the .htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What version of codeigniter you are using? And also do not leave your base url blank.

Comment: $root = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;

 is this right

Comment: You have a few base_url in there just have one and then put in your domain name `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';` or `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';`

Comment: What version of codeigniter your using?  CI2 or CI3

Comment: U mean like this @ wolfgang1983
`$config['base_url'] = 'http://mywedding.comxa.com/';`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 its ci3

Comment: CI3 does not use AUTO any more `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';`  and don't for get `http://`  like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://mywedding.comxa.com/';`

Comment: Here is some htaccess https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: so what should i put in `$config['uri_protocol']`

Comment: There config where has REQUEST_URI, QUERY_STRING, PATH_INFO I would use `REQUEST_URI` I do not think you should start with a fresh config.php

Comment: Also make sure controllers, models etc have the first letter of the file name and class name upper case. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Comment: I changed the first letter of the controller into upper case and I received this error...Any clue??

Message: mysqli::real_connect() [mysqli.real-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'a5168160_root'@'10.1.1.31' (using password: YES)

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 130

Comment: Might be your user name or password to database incorrect to what your 000webhosting is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While uppercase and lowercase letters doesn't matter In windows server, Linux is case sensitive. Therefore, the URLs are different for Linux even though the name seems to similar.

In addition, If you are using Codeigniter 3, the name of all classes and their filenames must be in capital letters.

Comment: Nice to see the accepted answer about this problem! Just the classes names & filenames, right? So doesn't need to capitalize each ajax url & links (`href` or `src`) inside all php files, right?? I'm afraid that would be a huge work.

Comment: @TaufikNurRahmanda, Yes, you don't have to change the URLs. Even when you loading the classes doesn't matter if you call them with capital letter or not. Codeigniter understand it. So, basically $this->load->model('modelname'); , $this->load->model('Modelname'); or $this->load->model('Modelname.php') are all the same for Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

try this htaccess: maybe **/$1** ut's the problem

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: also u need to set RewriteBase /